# Two VHost with same DocumentRoot but different SSL Certificate. Is that even possible?

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I can do this : https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

But I need to do that (note that the DocumentRoot is the same on purpose) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite2.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite2_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite2_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The website runs ok except with https error : when I load www.yoursite2.com in my browser, if I click to see the ssl certificate details, it shows me the certificate of www.yoursite.com instead of yoursite2 as expected.

I need this because the certificate does not come from the same authority and I cannot add every domains to the same certificate. One is from Digicert, the other is from Let's encrypt.

Using Apache 2.4.6

Thanks

Comment: I suspect all that is missing here is a directive "Listen 443" before the Virtualhost blocks.

Comment: It is there. My configuration is more complex that shown in the question. There are a few websites live and working well. I need to add the new domain but with another SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the example in my question actually works...

I mistyped the port in my configuration and put a port 433 instead of 443.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```